# How to handle concurrent requests on the back-end of an Uber like app?

Tags: rest, concurrency, backend, ondemand

### Background

I am looking to design the back-end for an on-demand service app, akin to Uber. In this app, and most others like it, we have many *buyers* who send requests for a service that must be forwarded to many *service-providers* providers, etc. - all in real time.

I am planning to create a single REST API for the back-end, implemented in Javascript/Node over a single Postgres database. This back-end would mediate between the buyers and service-providers by receiving buyer requests, matching buyers with available service-provider based on custom criteria, forwarding the requests to service-providers, etc.

With a real-time on-demand service like this, there are many race-conditions that can occur i.e. when multiple buyers are matched with the same service-provider at the same time. I was thinking to handle all of these cases with a web-API flavor of optimistic concurrency control (inspired by [this blog post](https://blog.4psa.com/rest-best-practices-managing-concurrent-updates/)).

### Questions

- Is a single REST API the right backend solution for this case?
- Are there any schemes, algorithms, frameworks, solutions out there
  that could handle concurrent service requests while also being
  reasonable performant and scalable*?

*Scalable to a reasonable degree, i.e. up to a magnitude of 1000s rather that Uber's millions